# Using a cte to retrieve a random record

Tags: sql, oracle, random, common-table-expression

I found the following code, which works fine. Could someone suggest a way how I can integrate the locations table into the cte so that I get a random location_id with every row. I suspect I need another union all but I'm unsure how to get the random location_id

In this example the locations table is consecutively ordered for ease of posting but that will not be the case all the time.

```
 CREATE TABLE schedule_hdr AS
SELECT level AS schedule_id,
   'Schedule ' || level AS schedule_name

 FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 2;

CREATE TABLE locations AS
 SELECT level AS location_id,
   'Door ' || level AS location_name,

CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'G' 
     END AS location_type

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 25;


 ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT location_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (location_id));



WITH random_times (     schedule_id,    datetime, lvl ) AS (
 SELECT schedule_id,
      TRUNC(sysdate)
      + 
 NUMTODSINTERVAL( FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,23*60)), 'MINUTE' ),
     1
FROM   schedule_hdr
 UNION ALL
SELECT schedule_id, 
     datetime + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,11)), 'MINUTE'),
     lvl + 1
FROM   random_times
WHERE  lvl < 5
)
SELECT schedule_id,
   datetime
FROM   random_times
ORDER BY schedule_id, datetime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want:

```sql
WITH random_times (     schedule_id,    datetime, lvl ) AS (
 SELECT schedule_id,
      TRUNC(sysdate)
      + 
 NUMTODSINTERVAL( FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,23*60)), 'MINUTE' ),
     1
FROM   schedule_hdr
 UNION ALL
SELECT schedule_id, 
     datetime + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,11)), 'MINUTE'),
     lvl + 1
FROM   random_times
WHERE  lvl < 5
)
SELECT
   schedule_id,
   datetime,
   loc.*
FROM   random_times
      ,locations loc
where loc.location_id = (
          select location_id
          from locations
          -- you need this predicate to disable subquery caching:
          where location_id*0 = schedule_id*0+lvl*0
          order by dbms_random.value()
          fetch first 1 row only
       )
ORDER BY schedule_id, datetime;
```

Comment: Assuming I have an employees table (employee_id, emp_name) and I want a random employee_id to be associated with a schedule_id should I just modify the where clause predicate? Thanks for your time, patience and expertise

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to know what is going on from this code snippet, but if you're aiming to seed new tables with data in a random order from base tables that have data, you could consider generating random values, then row_number ordering by them to give yourself a pseudo primary key (integer, incrementing):

```
SELECT 
  t.*,
  row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value(1,10)) as pseudopk 
FROM
  table
```

For example you have base data tables (or cte) like:

```
BasePerson
Name, Age
--------
John, 20
Mary, 30

BaseAddress
City
----
New York
Paris
Berlin

INSERT INTO RealAddress(ID, City)
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value(1,10)) pk, a.City 
  FROM BaseAddress
)
WHERE pk < 3 --2 people need 2 address

INSERT INTO RealPerson(ID, Name, Age, AddressID)
SELECT pk, Name, Age, pk
FROM(
  SELECT 
    row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value(1,10)) pk, 
    a.Name, 
    a.Age
  FROM BasePerson
)
```

It doesn't really matter that we reuse the number for both the person ID and their addressID, because the address data was randomised when it was inserted, so this is "people in a random order relative to their pk, linked to addresses in a random order relative to address's pk"